# How do I find the least x that satisfies this congruence properties?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Suppose $77x \equiv 1 \pmod{144}$ and $67x \equiv 3 \pmod{77}$, how do we find the least x that satisfies this relationship?

Here is what I did:

1. I expressed the first congruence relation in linear combination for $gcd(144,77)$, and I get $1 = 23(144) - 43(77)$.
2. Then I found the multiplicative inverse of 77 to be 101.

I did some computation and found the answer to be 4997, which is divisible by 101 to get 49.

How are all of these facts related? Is it legal to simply multiply the congruence relationships together to give something like $67 \times 77 \times x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {144 \times 77}$?

Comment: No, you can't multiply congruences.  The system $n\equiv 1\pmod 2,n\equiv 2\pmod 3$ has solution $n\equiv 5\pmod 6$ but if you multiplied you'd get $n^2\equiv 2\pmod 6$ which has no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lulu mentions in the comments, you can't just multiply congruences like that. Besides, that creates a quadratic congruence, and they're harder to solve than linear ones.

The usual way to solve simultaneous linear congruences involves an ancient algorithm known as the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Firstly, note that if $x$ is any solution, then $x + k \times 144 \times 77$ for any integer $k$ is another solution. $144 \times 77 = 11088$, so all solution are congruent to $x \mod 11088$.

To use the Chinese remainder theorem, we first need to express the congruences in the form $x \equiv a \mod m$.

You've already found that $77^{-1} \mod 144 \equiv 101$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm. So you also know how to find that  $67^{-1} \mod 77 \equiv 23$. Thus we can rewrite our simultaneous congruences as

$$x \equiv 101 \mod 144$$
and
$$x \equiv 69 \mod 77$$

We can now uses those inverses again to apply the Chinese remainder theorem. Note that $144 \equiv 67 \mod 77$, so we can recycle that previous result to show that $144^{-1} \mod 77 \equiv 23$

Consider $a \times 77 \times 101$ for any integer $a$. It's obviously $\equiv 0 \mod 77$, but $\equiv a \mod 144$. Similarly, $b \times 144 \times 23$ is $\equiv 0 \mod 144$ and $\equiv b \mod 77$ for any $b$. Thus

$$101 \times 77 \times 101 + 69 \times 144 \times 23$$

is $\equiv 101 \mod 144$ and $\equiv 69 \mod 77$. In other words, it's the simultaneous solution to both congruences! So

$$x \equiv 101 \times 77 \times 101 + 69 \times 144 \times 23 = 1014005 \equiv 4997 \mod 11088$$

As the linked Wikipedia article shows, it's easy to extend this algorithm to handle any number of simultaneous congruences. Usually, the moduli need to be mutually coprime, but sometimes you can get solutions when that's not the case.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 We're given $67x \equiv 3 \mod 77$, and we use the extended Euclidean algorithm to get $67\times23 \equiv 1 \mod 77$, that is $67^{-1}\equiv23 \mod 77$. So if we multiply both sides of the 1st equation by 23, we get $67\times67^{-1}\times x \equiv 3\times23 \mod 77$ or $x \equiv 69 \mod 77$

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will this question still be solvable suppose $67x \equiv 3 \pmod{76}$ or some other number instead? Does CRT only guarantee a solution and not an answer? The answer current seems to hinge on the fact that we can "cross multiply" to get some unique a. Is this the only way?

Comment: Also, what is the thinking process you used when you wrote "consider a ....for any b" that statement? Is this cross multiply a common strategy that occurs in number theory?

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 The problem with mod 76 is that 76 and 144 aren't coprime. Using mod 76, we get $67^{-1} \equiv 59 \mod 76$, and the 2nd congruence becomes $x \equiv 25 \mod 76$, but if we plug $x \equiv 101 \mod 144$ and $x \equiv 25 \mod 76$ into the CRT (Chinese remainder theorem), it doesn't work.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 Creating expressions of the form $a.f_1(x) + b.f_2(x) + c.f_3(x) \cdots$, such that as $x$ takes values from a set of $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots\}$ one of those functions evaluates to 1 and the rest evaluate to 0 is a fairly common technique. Apart from its use in the CRT, it's also used in [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

We have $$77x \equiv 1 \equiv 7777\pmod{144}\implies x\equiv 101 \pmod{144}$$ since $(144,77)=1$ and $$67x\equiv 3\equiv4623\pmod{77}\implies x\equiv69 \pmod{77}$$ since $(77,67)=1$.

Now for the first congruence, $$x=101, 245, ..., 4997$$ and $$4997\equiv69\pmod{77}$$ and since $144\times 77=11088$, $$\boxed{x\equiv4997\pmod{11088}}$$